# java.nio.*Buffer: put one element at a time vs from array

Tags: java, android, nio

Is there much overhead in the nio Buffer family put methods? I have a few FloatBuffers and ByteBuffers which need to hold between 4 and 8 elements, and the values aren't already held in an array. Is it more efficient to create a temporary array, populate that and call the put method once, or not bother with the array and call put for each element?

Comment: You could always time it yourself. Creating an array hardly seems worth the bother, unless it falls naturally out of the code.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about accepting answers, I didn't know about that.